# t-sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the following table

```
Title Jul-10  Aug-10 Sep-10 Oct-10 Nov-10  Dec-10 Jan-11  Feb-11 Mar-11 Apr-11 May-11 Jun-11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A      Null    M1     Null    M2     Null   Null   Null    Null   M3     Null   Null   Null
B      Null    M1     Null    Null   Null   Null   M2      Null   Null   Null   Null   Null
C      Null    Null   Null    Null   Null   M1     Null    Null   Null   Null   Null   Null
```

How can i select only the columns between a certain range.

```
For instance if input variables are:
-------------------------------------
@start = 'Oct-10'
@end = 'Apr-11'
```

Then output will be:

```
Title  Oct-10  Nov-10  Dec-10  Jan-11   Feb-11   Mar-11   Apr-11
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A      M2      Null    Null     Null     Null     M3       Null   
B      Null    Null    Null     M2       Null     Null     Null
C      Null    Null    M1       Null     Null     Null     Null
```

Comment: It looks like the column headers are months in a year, are they?

Comment: @marc_s: The input (source table) is from the answer of "Help with t-sql query". I wanted to augment the same question but thought a seperate question will reduce confusion by concentrating on second part.

Comment: Do you have the ability to provide valid dates in your parameters? You use 'Oct-10', can you send 10-1-2010 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier way to do your pivot, using a handy stored procedure named pivot_query
([code is here](http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query.sql), [examples here](http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query_examples.sql) ).  This way you use your start and end date criteria to first limit the data to be pivoted, thus limiting the columns you get after the pivot.

The [fn_MonthRange() function](http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/fn_MonthRange.sql) is a recursive CTE that provides a table of dates a month apart between the start and end dates, which you then OUTER join to your data. That will fill in any missing months.

([fn_DateRange()](http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/fn_DateRange.txt) is similar, but works for arbitrary time segments like "every 15 minutes", every hour, every 3 days etc.)

```
    create table #testdata
       (
       id          integer,
       Title       varchar(20),
       TheDate     datetime,
       Metadata    varchar(20)
       )
    go


    insert into #testdata values(1,'A','08/01/2010','M1')
    insert into #testdata values(1,'A','10/05/2010','M2')
    insert into #testdata values(1,'A','03/15/2011','M3')
    insert into #testdata values(2,'B','09/20/2010','M1')
    insert into #testdata values(2,'B','01/15/2011','M2')
    insert into #testdata values(3,'C','12/15/2010','M1')
    go

    declare @mySQL       varchar(MAX);
    declare @StartDate   varchar(20);
    declare @EndDate     varchar(20);

    set @StartDate = '08/01/2010';
    set @EndDate   = '03/15/2011';

    set @mySQL = '
    select
       id,
       Title,
       Left(Datename(month, TheDate),3) + ''-'' + right(cast(Year(theDate) as varchar(4)),2) monyr,
       Metadata
    from
   dbo.fn_MonthRange( ''' + @StartDate + ''',''' + @EndDate + ''') dr

   LEFT OUTER JOIN #testdata td
      on (td.TheDate between dr.startdate and dr.enddate )
where
   dr.StartDate between ''' + @StartDate + ''' and ''' + @EndDate + '''';

    exec pivot_query @mySQL, 'Title', 'monyr','max(Metadata)'
    go

    Result:
Title                Aug-10               Dec-10               Feb-11               Jan-11               Mar-11               Nov-10               Oct-10               Sep-10               
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
A                    M1                   NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 M3                   NULL                 M2                   NULL                 
B                    NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 M2                   NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 M1                   
C                    NULL                 M1                   NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 
None                 NULL                 NULL                 None                 NULL                 NULL                 None                 NULL                 NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the output should contain Jan-09 to Dec-15 columns since the input range was '01/01/2009' to '12/31/2015'.

Comment: Ah yes, the "filler" function - added that into the query as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that it makes more sense for the application to do than SQl. Do a:

```
 select field1, field2 from your table between date1 and date2.
```

Then let the application pivot the data. Typically applications can pivot data more efficiently than SQL can. Espcially when the number of columns vary each time you run it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the table is pivoted, by which I mean that the columns should probably be rows. This type of design is very human readable, but not very queryable.

Take a look at the UNPIVOT operator. You should be able to use it to get a data set with rows that you can filter against, and then when you're done you can PIVOT back into this format if you need to.

Here's an article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

*UNPIVOT performs almost the reverse operation of PIVOT, by rotating columns into rows.*

Comment: @Biran MacKay: but i dont want to rotate columns. I just want to filter the columns based on the range. Is that even possible?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But if you rotate them in query, then you'll have rows instead of columns, and you CAN filter on rows! :)

Comment: (and then when you're done with all that, you can pivot it back to into this shape if you want -- basically this design causes you to perform an extra step).

Comment: @Brian MacKay: Actually I create the input table by applying PIVOT. Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071799/help-with-t-sql-query

I am failing to understand how can i unpivot and then again pivot to get the desired results. Can you pls. show me the code to pivot again to get all the required columns within the range?

Comment: Take a look at the article I linked to -- towards the bottom there's an UNPIVOT example that shows you how to rotate columns back into rows. It's exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Also... If you're actually doing a PIVOT, might it be possible to do the filter before you do that? That's the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. I have done some testing. I will give you the code to play with but because of how NULLs are handled with unpivot you will lose the contiguous range of months. They could be added back with the pivot, but that would require a numbers table, etc. Too much for me to do a 5:02! =)

```
WITH datepivot
     AS (SELECT title,
                Convert(DATETIME, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(datecol, 'Jan', '01-01'), 'Feb', '02-01'), 'Mar', '03-01'), 'Apr', '04-01'), 'May', '05-01'), 'Jun', '06-01'), 'Jul', '07-01'), 'Aug', '08-01'), 'Sep', '09-01'), 'Oct', '10-01'), 'Nov', '11-01'), 'Dec', '12-01')) datecol,
                datecol                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                origdatecol,
                Isnull(code, 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        code
         FROM   (SELECT title,
                        [Jul-10],
                        [Aug-10],
                        [Sep-10],
                        [Oct-10],
                        [Nov-10],
                        [Dec-10],
                        [Jan-11],
                        [Feb-11],
                        [Mar-11],
                        [Apr-11],
                        [May-11],
                        [Jun-11]
                 FROM   test) test UNPIVOT (code FOR datecol IN ([Jul-10], [Aug-10], [Sep-10], [Oct-10], [Nov-10], [Dec-10], [Jan-11], [Feb-11], [Mar-11], [Apr-11], [May-11], [Jun-11]))AS dateunpivot)
--SELECT * from datepivot   --uncomment to view unpivoted data
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT title,
               code,
               origdatecol
        FROM   datepivot
        WHERE  datecol BETWEEN '10-01-2010' AND '04-01-2011') a PIVOT (Max(code) FOR origdatecol IN ([Jul-10], [Aug-10], [Sep-10], [Oct-10], [Nov-10], [Dec-10], [Jan-11], [Feb-11], [Mar-11], [Apr-11], [May-11], [Jun-11])) b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the necessary SQL select statement, then use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to run the query.

Here's an example of how to generate the month column names:

```
DECLARE  @nextMonth TABLE(
    currentMonth CHAR(3),
    nextMonth CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @nextMonth(currentMonth, nextMonth)
SELECT 'Jan', 'Feb' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Feb', 'Mar' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mar', 'Apr' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apr', 'May' UNION ALL
SELECT 'May', 'Jun' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jun', 'Jul' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jul', 'Aug' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aug', 'Sep' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sep', 'Oct' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Oct', 'Nov' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nov', 'Dec' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dec', 'Jan'

DECLARE @start char(6), @end char(6), @current char(6), @columnNames varchar(1000)
SELECT @start = 'Oct-10', @end = 'Apr-11'

SET @current = @start;
WHILE (@current <> @end)
BEGIN
    IF (@columnNames IS NULL)
        SET @columnNames = @current;
    ELSE
        SET @columnNames = @columnNames + ', ' + @current;

    SELECT @current = nextMonth + '-' + LTRIM(STR(case LEFT(@current, 3) WHEN 'Dec' THEN 1+RIGHT(@current, 2) ELSE RIGHT(@current, 2) END))
    FROM @nextMonth
    WHERE currentMonth = left(@current, 3)
END

SELECT @columnNames
```

This gives me:

```
Oct-10, Nov-10, Dec-10, Jan-11, Feb-11, Mar-11
```

Incrementing the year could be done more explicitly.  I took advantage of the automatic casting.

I only have access to SQL Server 2005, so there maybe a much better way in 2008.