# Pivot or Transpose SQL Server 2005 table data without row-by-row processing

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot-table

Is it possible to do the following in SQL Server 2005 without row-by-row processing? If so, how? :)

My table is like this:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ CustomerID ║ FirstName ║  LastName  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║          1 ║ George    ║ Washington ║
║          2 ║ Benjamin  ║ Franklin   ║
║          3 ║ Thomas    ║ Jefferson  ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I to output the above table like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║   Field    ║ IntValue ║ TextValue  ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ CustomerID ║ 1        ║ NULL       ║
║ FirstName  ║ NULL     ║ George     ║
║ LastName   ║ NULL     ║ Washington ║
║ CustomerID ║ 2        ║ NULL       ║
║ FirstName  ║ NULL     ║ Benjamin   ║
║ LastName   ║ NULL     ║ Franklin   ║
║ CustomerID ║ 3        ║ NULL       ║
║ FirstName  ║ NULL     ║ Thomas     ║
║ LastName   ║ NULL     ║ Jefferson  ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: Why does this transposition have to be done in SQL Server? This seems more appropriate for the presentation tier (which has to loop through the rows to present them anyway).

Comment: I didn't say this had to be done in SQL Server. If need be I can create a C# app or do a set based loop and bust it out row-by-row. I'm beginning to do more and more dba work and I'm asked to do several one-off selects. So I would like to know if there is an alternative to row-by-row processing for the above request.

Comment: Where is the select being consumed?

Comment: Is this row-by-row to you: `select 'CustomerID' as Field, CustomerID as IntValue, null as TextValue
from MyTable
union all
select 'FirstName', null, FirstName
from MyTable
union all
select 'LastName', null, LastName
from MyTable`

Comment: I wrote a stored proc to make this easier to do, [here is a description of it (plus code)][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072964/t-sql-select-query/3073522#3073522

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - These are mostly one-time selects within SSMS that are saved directly from the result set to CSV and then I place them out on an FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only scans the table once (Borrowing the table variable from @Aaron's answer).

```
SELECT Field, 
       IntValue, 
       TextValue 
FROM   @x 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'CustomerID', CustomerID,  NULL 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 'FirstName', NULL, FirstName
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 'LastName', NULL, LastName) 
        CA(Field, IntValue, TextValue) 
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Answer (score 2):

While I still suggest this pivoting is much better performed at the layer where the SELECT is consumed, here is one idea.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(CustomerID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(32), LastName NVARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x SELECT 1, 'George', 'Washington'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Benjamin', 'Franklin'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Thomas', 'Jefferson';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT 
    Field = 'CustomerID', IntValue = CustomerID, TextValue = NULL,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID)
    FROM @x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    Field = 'FirstName', NULL, FirstName,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID)
    FROM @x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Field = 'LastName', NULL, LastName,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID)
    FROM @x
)
SELECT Field, IntValue, TextValue
FROM x
ORDER BY rn, Field;
```

Why is this better done at the presentation later? Because this "solution" will scan the table three times. And the consumer is still going to have to use a loop to display the results...