# Square bracket surrounded comma delimited list from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, pivot-table

I have a list of entries from a table which am trying to use in a pivot table query as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [week_end], [identify_entity], [count_num]
FROM weekly_counts_t
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX([count_num])
    FOR [identify_entity] IN ([a], [b] ...and so on)
) as pvt
```

for the `'for in'` query below am trying to use the list from a select query from some other table
`FOR [identify_entity] IN (select identify_entity from temp_table)` instead of
`FOR [identify_entity] IN ([a], [b] ...and so on)` which is a manual process of keying in entries.

So now, I need the list as entries in square brackets and are separated by comma.Could some one please help me out ?Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283674/pivot-sql-values-from-subquery/2283909#2283909.  A couple of those answers look similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
DECLARE @identify_entity  NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @identify_entity = '';

SELECT @identify_entity = @identify_entity + ',[' + [identify_entity] + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [identify_entity] FROM weekly_counts_t) t

SET @identify_entity = STUFF(@identify_entity, 1, 1,'')

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM
            (
            SELECT [week_end], [identify_entity], [count_num]
            FROM weekly_counts_t
            ) AS source
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX([count_num])
                FOR [identify_entity] 
                IN ('+ @identify_entity  +')
            ) as pvt'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```